# How to change the content of distributedCache when the job is done?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is there any way to change the content of the file associated as the distributedCache when the job is done and use as a new distributedCache in another map/reduce job coming after?

Answer (score 2):

Check [TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.1.1/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java) code for more details. Hadoop keeps a reference count on how many tasks are using the files in the DistributedCache. If the count drops to 0, then the file marked for deletion. So, at the end of the job the files in the DistributedCache are cleaned or else they would keep on piling on the node across jobs.

So, you can't change the files in the distributed cache and use it in the consecutive job.

Comment: So, I have a map-reduce job which is inside a loop. That is, depending on the values that reducers outputs, it decides to repeat the whole process again or not. However, mappers read a value from distributedCache. The values in the distributedCache change in each iteration. Is there any way to do that?